# How can I make a binary tree array from the array?

Tags: php, arrays, graph, neo4j, binary-tree

I have the array of persons:

```
array(
    array(
       'name' => 'John',
       'id' => 1,
       'mother_id' => 2,
       'father_id' => 3
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'Lucy',
       'id' => 2,
       'mother_id' => 5,
       'father_id' => 4
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'Jim',
       'id' => 3,
       'mother_id' => 7,
       'father_id' => 9
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'Paul',
       'id' => 4,
       'mother_id' => 534,
       'father_id' => 54
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'Laura',
       'id' => 5,
       'mother_id' => 554,
       'father_id' => 51
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'Vanessa',
       'id' => 7,
       'mother_id' => 5354,
       'father_id' => 514
    ),
    array(
       'name' => 'Adam',
       'id' => 9,
       'mother_id' => 245354,
       'father_id' => 514234
    ),
);
```

And I want to get this:

```
array(
array(
    'person' => array(
        'name' => 'John',
        'id' => 1,
        'mother_id' => 2,
        'father_id' => 3
    ),
    'parents' => array(
        'mother' => array(
              'person' => array(
                  'name' => 'Lucy',
                  'id' => 2,
                  'mother_id' => 5,
                  'father_id' => 4
              ),
              'parents' => array(
                  'mother' => array(
                      'person' => array(
                          'name' => 'Laura',
                          'id' => 5,
                          'mother_id' => 554,
                          'father_id' => 51
                      ),
                      'parents' => array(...)
                  ),
                  'father' => array(
                        'person' => array(
                            'name' => 'Paul',
                            'id' => 4,
                            'mother_id' => 534,
                            'father_id' => 54
                        ),
                        'parents' => array(...)
                   ), 
              )
        ),
        'father' => ...
)
```

So John is a child that has mother and father, father has mother and father, mother has mother and father and etc, and write a script that do something but not what I want exactly

```
function parseTree(& $tree, $root = null) {
    $return = null;

    foreach ($tree as $key=> $item){

        if ($item['id'] == $root){

            $return = [
                'person' => $item,
                'parents' => [
                    'father' => parseTree($tree, $item['father_id'])
                ]
            ];

            unset ($tree[$key]);
        }elseif($item['id'] == $root){
            $return = [
                'person' => $item,
                'parents' => [
                    'father' => parseTree($tree, $item['mother_id'])
                ]
            ];

            unset ($tree[$key]);
        }
        elseif ($root == null) {

            $return = [
              'person' => $item,
              'parents' => [
                  'father' => parseTree($tree, $item['father_id']),
                  'mother' => parseTree($tree, $item['mother_id'])
               ]
            ];

            unset ($tree[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

How can I make it work? Or maybe there are some proper libraries for that?

Comment: are these mysql database results?

Comment: No it's from neo4j

Comment: Theres probably a way to create a Query that does this for you through Neo4j. Find that out first, since It makes sense to do it at the database level. If you are certain you cant do it, then you can look into PHP.

Comment: Already did it, tried a lot of stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it. I would do it in this manner:

```
function parseTree(&$tree, $root = null)
{
    $return = null;
    foreach ($tree as $key => $item) {
        if ($root == null || $item['id'] == $root) {
            $return = [
                'person' => $item,
                'parents' => [
                    'father' => parseTree($tree, $item['father_id']),
                    'mother' => parseTree($tree, $item['mother_id'])
                ]
            ];
            unset ($tree[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Man, you my hero! Thanks a lot! It's perfect :)